# how can i cast the long to table correctly?

Tags: sql, linq, casting

This is my code:

```
public IQueryable<User> getuserid(string email)
{
    return from m in DBL.Users
           where m.Email == email
           select m.ID;
}
```

I keep having this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<long> to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<User>'. An explicit conversion exists.

How should I cast it correctly?

Comment: `select m.ID;` select `ID` that `long` but you try return `IQueryable<User>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a matter of casting, it's a matter of your function return type being different than what you're returning in your linq statement. If you want a list of longs returned, change the return type of the method.

```
public IQueryable<User> getuserid(string email)
```

to

```
public IQueryable<long> getuserid(string email)
```

Comment: would it help if I change it String  and cast it into the integer when i needed it?

Comment: @nimasharify change it and try it.

Comment: @nimasharify No, it would not help and why would you want it to be a string until you need it? It's a long, keep it as a long.